# How to make Maven assembly plugin dependencySets descriptor to include dependencies as defined in POM file?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

For example, a POM dependency declaration (this is just for demo purpose and not my actual code):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>..</dependency>
    <dependency>..</dependency>
```

My assembly dependencySets descriptor:

```
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*:jar</include>
            </includes>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

From what I observed, the assembly will have extra jars (transitive) from `logback-classic` and my POM dependencies will not. How to make the assembly resolving the same jars as the POM? If possible I do not want to have duplicated exclusion again in the assembly `dependencySets`.

NOTE: I'm using `Maven 3.2.3` in `Windows 8.1` running on `Java 6`.

Comment: You should add the `<useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies> which is true by default in the descriptor. Furthermore you don't need to give an `<include>*:jar</include>`.  See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Perhaps I'm not being clear in stating my questions. Actually I have another dependencies other than `logback-classic` whom transitive dependencies I don't intend to exclude. Using `useTransitiveDependencies` as `false` will exclude all the transitive dependencies of the plugins I declared, not only the intentionally excluded one (`logback-classic`)

Comment: If you have such thing you need to define two dependencySet entries one which include the logback and other.

Comment: hmm, yes, I think it will do the trick. Didn't think about this. Thanks. However, as mentioned above I try not to have duplicated exclusions again in assembly as I have to edit twice when there are dependencies changes. Currently I copy all the dependencies to a temporary folder using maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies and include them in the assembly using the fileset.

Comment: The dependency-copy way took longer to build and the cleaner solution is via maven-assembly.

Comment: @khmarbaise maven-assembly _is_ the cleaner way, but the solution you propose is case-specific. Can you think of a generic way to do this for anyone? I deliberately created [a duplicate for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32461192/1734119), with additional constraints and details. Feel free to have a look if you have something to propose.